# error :there must be at least one name or distribution list in the to cc or bcc box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, outlook

I am trying open new mail message in outook 2013 with bcc field filled from database

if I select all rows from datagridview it throws exception error "error :there must be at least one name or distribution list in the to cc or bcc box"

is there is any limitation for number of emails to be added in the bcc field?
here is my code

```
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim AppOutlook As New Outlook.Application

    mail = AppOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    mail.Subject = "Sample Message"
    mail.To = "abc@xyz.com"
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgLoad.Rows
        'If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then
        If Me.dgLoad(0, 0).Value = Me.chkBox.Checked Then

            'End If
            Dim address As String = row.Cells(6).Value
            Dim recipBcc As Outlook.Recipient = mail.Recipients.Add(address)
            recipBcc.Type = CInt(Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC)
        End If
    Next

    mail.Display(True)
```

please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting that message when `row.Cells(6).Value` is an empty string. Try adding an if statement to skip the next three statements if that's the case.